# Facebook post status get session from one class to another

Tags: android, facebook

I want to add a post to facebook button for my app to share something and I think there is something wrong with the way I use my codes. To begin with I have my login class wherein it handles all the login part of facebook then stores all the data (username, email, fb_id) I need in an intent where I can pass all the values from login class to another then I finish the class cause I don't want a user to go back on the login page after they clicked the back button. On my details activity there is one button which when I click it needs to post to facebook the message I've set but the problem is when I use mFacebook.isSessionValid() to check is the login is valid for the user it returns nothing so what I think is that all the information on my Facebook classes are refreshed (I'm not sure about that part though). Well that's what I need on how to post a message on another class.

Here's the post codes I use:

```
private void postToFacebook() { 
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
        mProgress.show();

        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "My Message");
        params.putString("name", "My app name");
        params.putString("caption", "caption here");
        params.putString("link", "URL PAGE HERE");
        params.putString("description", "DESCRIPTIONS HERE");
        params.putString("picture", "IMAGE URL");
        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());

    }

    private final class WallPostListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        public void onComplete(final String response) {
            mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mProgress.cancel();

                    Toast.makeText(ScoreScreen.this, "Posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is my code for showing the next page after the login page (Main):

```
SessionStore.saveName(username, Main.this);
            //IF ONLY SUCCESS IN FETCHING RECORDS
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, SplashScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("fname", fname);
            i.putExtra("lname", lname);
            i.putExtra("eadd", eadd);
            i.putExtra("fbid", fbid);
            i.putExtra("gender", gender);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Connected to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Main.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using SessionStore.restore. I'm not so sure but I think the session ends after I finish the Main activity and moved to the next class. Will review the issues later.